# cmd: run exe from a folder with dynamic name

Tags: windows, cmd

I have an exe file, say, **C:\Programs\tools\4.0.97869\program.exe**
This, obviously, version number may vary, but I'm totally sure that it will always be `4.0.something`

I can execute some command from batch file, specifying path to that exe like this:

```
"C:\Programs\tools\4.0.97869\program.exe" /option:Key somevalue
```

Which works perfectly fine. However, I would like to place a wildcard here, for example like this:

```
C:\Programs\tools\4.0.*\program.exe
```

Since I can perfectly navigate like this using `cd`

1. I do not want to specify that exe in `Path`
2. I do not want to cd to that directory and call `program.exe` from there

> It there a way to specify first matching directory which has a
>   necessary file to execute in one line?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you open to use PowerShell?

Comment: `cd C:\prgrams\tools\4.0.* & program.exe`?

Comment: @Joey any possible analog w/o cd ?

Comment: What should be done if there are multiple "4.0.something" directories found?

Comment: @lit pick any first, no matter. Minor-major version is not what matters right now. But in fact, there is always one folder, just names are different

Comment: @TEHEMPRAH - Is your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses a PowerShell script:

```
$pathPattern = 'C:\Programs\tools\4.0.*\program.exe'

if(!(Test-Path $pathPattern)){
    throw "Could not find a single executable"
}

$paths = Get-Item -Path $pathPattern

Invoke-Expression $paths[0]
```

Comment: Might consider! Though not one line.

Comment: @TEHEMPRAH Save the script, invoking the script will be 1 line ;)

Comment: For some reason PS is not an option on that system D: Upvoted anyway.

Comment: Probably good to `Test-Path -Path 'C:\Programs\tools\4.0.*\program.exe'` before using `Get-Item` on it.

Comment: @lit agreed. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A PowerShell solution would be a better idea. If only cmd.exe can be used, the following might work. It is not a one-liner. Store this in a .bat file and CALL it. It works by running the first "program.exe" it can find. It tries to get the most recent one by ordering the directory search as most recent first.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET EXITCODE=0

SET "EXEWILD=C:\Programs\tools\4.0.*"
FOR /F %%d IN ("%EXEWILD%") DO (SET "EXEBASE=%%~dpd")

IF NOT EXIST "%EXEWILD%" (
    ECHO ERROR: Tool directory "%EXEWILD%" does not exist.
    SET EXITCODE=4
    GOTO TheEnd
)

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%d IN (`DIR /B /O-D "%EXEWILD%"`) DO (
    IF EXIST "%EXEBASE%\%%~d\program.exe" (
        "%EXEBASE%%%~d\program.exe" %*
        SET EXITCODE=!ERRORLEVEL!
        GOTO TheEnd
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO WARNING: program.exe not found in "%EXEBASE%\%%~d"
    )
)

:TheEnd
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```